# Sending Email via Java: Windows Outlook adds trailing spaces?

Tags: java, html, css, email, outlook

I am using the following simple html to generate an Outlook email:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></head><body><p>Hello World</p></body></html>
```

However, the generated email has trailing spaces when you double click on the line in Windows Outlook:

[image]

Is there any way to git rid of this space ? I don't see the issue in Mac Outlook or online version of the Outlook.

Comment: This is likely related to present CSS. So please share the related CSS to your HTML, so we can hep you out.

Comment: @Demian No css....its literally that one line given above...the yellow color is just highlighting the space - let me remove it